# Find all the points on the cone $z^2=x^2+4y^2$ that are the closest to the point $(0,0,c)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, qcqp

> From all the points on the cone $z^2=x^2+4y^2$ find the closest to the point $(0,0,c)$. State explicitly the minimal distance. $c$ is a constant.

Lagrange multipliers can be used here.

Let the constraint function $g=x^2+4y^2-z^2$.

Let the minimization function $f=(x-0)^2+(y-0)^2+(z-c)^2$ as function of finding the distance in between 2 points ion 3d space. We're also going to keep $f$ in squares so we don't have to get the factor out $z$ from the ellipse equation.

Then we have:
$$
\nabla g=\langle2x, 8y,-2z \rangle\\
\nabla f=\langle 2x, 2y,2(z-c)\rangle
$$

So:
$$
\begin{cases}
2x=k\cdot2x\\
2y=k\cdot 8y\\
2(z-c)=k\cdot(-2z)
\end{cases}
$$

We have that $k=\frac{1}{4}$ then $x=0$ and $z=\frac{4c}{5}$.
If we plug those values into the ellipse equation we get that:
$$
c^2=\frac{125y^2}{4}\Rightarrow c=\pm\frac{\sqrt{125}y}{2}
$$

So the points would be $(0,y,\frac{\sqrt{125}y}{2})$ and $(0,y,-\frac{\sqrt{125}y}{2})$.

First I think something is wrong with my calculations (although I double checked it). Also I'm not sure what does this mean that we have 2 points and how am I supposed to know which one is the minimum.

Comment: Consdier $c$ to be fixed and that you should be solving for $y$ in terms if $c.$ Not the other way around.  Also think about the geometry of the problem.  for any point on the cone, there is a second point that is equidistant to $c.$

Comment: @DougM then $y=\pm \frac{2c}{\sqrt{125}}$ and we have 2 points: $(0,\frac{2c}{\sqrt{125}}, c)$ and $(0,-\frac{2c}{\sqrt{125}}, c)$ right?

Comment: @DougM also does it make sense that $x=0$?

Comment: @Yos yes, exactly

Comment: $z = \frac {4c}{5}$ ...  and how do you get $125$ ?  But $x$ does equal $0.$  Consider the geometry of the problem and that should be clear.

Comment: @DougM First we have $z=\frac{4c}{5}$ then the constraint equation is $z^2=4y^2\Rightarrow \frac{(4c)^2}{5^2}=4y^2 |:4 \Rightarrow \frac{4c^2}{125}=y^2 \Rightarrow y=\pm \frac{2c}{\sqrt{125}}$

Comment: Alternative solution $y=0$ and $k=1$, then $c = 4z$

Comment: @ yos $5^2 = 25$

Comment: @gt6989b  $y=0, k=1$ does solve the equations, and finds an interesting point, $(\frac 14 c, 0 , \frac 14 c)$ but it is not the minimal distance.

Comment: @amd I'm not sure what you're referring to, what subtraction?

Comment: @amd you're right I meant pluses there, I'll correct that

Comment: @gt6989b how did you get $z=x=\frac{1}{4}c$? If $k=1$ then $2(z-c)=-2z \Rightarrow z=\frac{c}{2}$

Comment: @amd I'd appreciate if you could confirm that the correct points should be $(0,\pm \frac{2c}{5}, \frac{4c}{5})$ and $(\pm \frac{c}{2}, 0,\frac{c}{2})$ because I just noticed that what I wrote is not correct but nobody corrected me

Comment: Yes, those are the stationary points corresponding to $k=1/4$ and $k=1$, respectively, but you should also check the distances of these points from $(0,0,c)$ to see which is really the minimum.

Comment: @amd Thank you and $(0, \pm \frac{2c}{5}, \frac{4c}{5})$ is the min

Comment: Notice that the values of $k$ that you get are reciprocals of the eigenvalues of the quadratic form. This is not a coincidence.

Comment: In a few weeks I'll know what eigenvalues are :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimizing the *squared* distance,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & x^2 + y^2 + (z-c)^2\\ \text{subject to} & z^2 = x^2 + 4 y^2\end{array}$$

Let the Lagrangian be

$$\mathcal L (x,y,z,\lambda) := x^2 + y^2 + (z-c)^2 + \lambda (x^2 + 4 y^2 - z^2)$$

Taking the partial derivatives and finding where they vanish, we obtain

$$\begin{array}{rl} (1 + \lambda) \, x &= 0\\ (1 + 4\lambda) \, y &= 0\\ (1 - \lambda) \, z &= c\\ x^2 + 4 y^2 - z^2 &= 0\\\end{array}$$

We have two cases to consider.

---

$\color{blue}{\boxed{\lambda = -1}}$

In this case, $y = 0$ and $z = \frac c2$. The value of $x$ is given by

$$x = \pm \sqrt{ z^2 - 4 y^2 } = \pm \frac c2$$

Hence, we have the two points

$$(x,y,z) = \left( \pm \frac c2, 0, \frac c2 \right)$$

whose squared distance from $(0,0,c)$ is $\frac{c^2}{2}$.

---

$\color{blue}{\boxed{\lambda = - \frac 14}}$

In this case, $x = 0$ and $z = \frac{4c}{5}$. The value of $y$ is given by

$$y = \pm \frac 12 \sqrt{ z^2 - x^2 } = \pm \frac{2c}{5}$$

Hence, we have the two points

$$(x,y,z) = \left( 0, \pm \frac{2c}{5}, \frac{4c}{5} \right)$$

whose squared distance from $(0,0,c)$ is $\frac{c^2}{5} < \frac{c^2}{2}$. This is the **minimal** *squared* distance.

---

#### Example

Let $c = 5$. Hence, the points on the cone closest to $(0,0,5)$ are $(x,y,z) = ( 0, \pm 2, 4 )$. Here is a plot of the cone and the line segment whose endpoints are $(0,0,5)$ and $( 0, 2, 4)$

[image]

The length of the line segment is $\sqrt 5$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It is infinite elliptic cone May be it can help you to decide.

Comment: @ Ilya Telefus you should post a more detailed answer and give at least the final correct answer